# HTML from servlet response using ajax is not being executed in JSP page

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsp, servlets

My problem is kinda weird. I have a JSP page that calls servlet using JQuery/ajax on combobox change. Everything works fine, I get the response but html is displayed as text. Other thing worth mentioning is when I call servlet directly by URL, everything is fine.

Servlet response code:

```
for(int i=0;i<tabstr.length;i++){
        wyjscie.println(i+": "+tabstr[i]+" <br>");
    }
```

JSP ajax call:

```
$('#com2').change(function() {
                $.get('filtr', function(responseText) {
                    $('#result').text(responseText);
                });
            });
```

result is an ID of a DIV inside JSP page. I've done some servlets without ajax in the past and I didn't encounter this problem before. Any idea how to deal with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to set as html not text try this

```
$('#result').html(responseText);
```

Comment: I had to wait few minutes before I could accept, done it as soon as it was possible :P

Answer (score 0):

I think your server doesn't specify the mime type of the response. So you have to specify it or you can  specify `dataType` in you ajax call.

```
$.ajax({
   url : "myUrl",
   dataType : "json",
   data : {
     param1 : value1,                   
   }
});
```

[ajax api:](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

> **dataType**: The type of data that you're expecting back from the server. If none
>   is specified, jQuery will try to infer it based on the MIME type of
>   the response...

Comment: Thanks for your time, I appreciate it but I already found the solution - see Ramesh's post.